# SQL - select column if exists in OLEQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists, oledbconnection

At some customers I use an older database but now I have to add another column for newer customers. My program shall now query the new column if it exists and use NULL if it does not.

Using C# and OLEQuery this is working so far:

```
string sql = @"SELECT i.[ID] AS cID, 
                        pg.[Name], 
                        pg.[ID] AS pgid, 
                        i.[time],
                        defect = CASE i.[defect] WHEN 0 THEN 'OK' WHEN 1 THEN 'NOK' END,                                           
                  FROM inspection AS i WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN programs as pg ON i.programid = pg.[ID]
                  WHERE i.[time] BETWEEN ... ///SOME MORE CODE IS FOLLOWING HERE!
                    ";
```

But now I want to add into this the (may/may not) existing column timeTo.

```
string sql = @"SELECT i.[ID] AS cID, 
                        pg.[Name], 
                        pg.[ID] AS pgid, 
                        i.[time],
                        defect = CASE i.[defect] WHEN 0 THEN 'OK' WHEN 1 THEN 'NOK' END,                      
                        timeTo = CASE i.[timeTo] WHEN EXISTS THEN i.[timeTo] ELSE NULL END                     
                  FROM inspection AS i WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN programs as pg ON i.programid = pg.[ID]
                  WHERE i.[time] BETWEEN ... //SOME MORE CODE IS FOLLOWING HERE!
                    ";
```

I know it is difficult with this "exists" keyword but is there any "one-line" solution? I found several additional case select solutions. As I need this solution in several places with different columns the case select solutions do not fit. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Which rdbms are you using? eg sql-server, mysql or something else?

Comment: Sorry, it is sql-server.

Comment: By `exists`, do you mean is not `null`?

Comment: Slightly off-topic; Using `nolock` in production queries can be [very dangerous](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).  `NoLock` can miss rows, return duplicates and include uncommitted records.

Comment: That the column: timeTo is actually present in the database.

Comment: thanks @destination-data - as this is some legacy code I am working, I will check this "nolock".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server won't allow you to reference a field that does not exist.  I suspect this is because the query optimizer cannot generate an execution plan that includes non-existent fields.

Your app will need to:

1. Identify which version of the db it is working with.
2. Choose the appropriate queries.
3. Ensure it handles missing data (either by turning off functionality that relies on the new field or by selecting an appropriate default value).

Answer (score 0):

You could do an if statement and query the system tables. You'd need to do this in dynamic sql for it to parse.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

if exists (
    select 1 from sys.columns c
    inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
    where c.name = 'timeTo' and t.name = 'inspection')
begin
    set @sql = 'SELECT i.[ID] AS cID, 
        pg.[Name], 
        pg.[ID] AS pgid, 
        i.[time],
        defect = CASE i.[defect] WHEN 0 THEN ''OK'' WHEN 1 THEN ''NOK'' END,                      
        timeTo = CASE i.[timeTo] WHEN EXISTS THEN i.[timeTo] ELSE NULL END                     
    FROM inspection AS i WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN programs as pg ON i.programid = pg.[ID]
    WHERE i.[time] BETWEEN ... //SOME MORE CODE IS FOLLOWING HERE!';
end
else 
begin
    set @sql = 'SELECT i.[ID] AS cID, 
        pg.[Name], 
        pg.[ID] AS pgid, 
        i.[time],
        defect = CASE i.[defect] WHEN 0 THEN ''OK'' WHEN 1 THEN ''NOK'' END,                                           
    FROM inspection AS i WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN programs as pg ON i.programid = pg.[ID]
    WHERE i.[time] BETWEEN ... ///SOME MORE CODE IS FOLLOWING HERE!';
end
exec (@sql);
```

Comment: Yes thank you! I have done something like this now - but I was hoping /searching for a more elegant way (one-line-of-code solution).